# FacebookAppId error in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am integrate facebook with ios.  But when I run app, it gives following error.

```
'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'
```

Below is my plist detail.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FacebookAppID should not contain "fb".

your FacebookAppID should be 1375520439335416

and Item 0 is correct so no need to change that.

See this example from facebook developer site:

[image: plist file for facebook]